# How to log into the database when each Job has been dispatched in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

In my application I need to log when each job is dispatched, retried and executed. The reason why I need this log is to detect whether on a failure the job is re-dispatched or not.

Also I need to keep 1 month long the job dispatch.

In another words I need to log:

- Time dispatched,
- Time redispatched,
- Time finished
- error that caused re-dispatch
- where the job has been redispatched.

Is there some sort of trigger in laravel 5.7 that allows you to do custom logs during job dispatch?

So far I have seen that there are the `jobs` and `failed_jobs` tables that contains only ephemeral information only during the job execution. After job excecution records are removed.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#job-events

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#failed-job-events

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build it yourself, then [Job events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#job-events)

If you want to have a dashboard and logs for everything you mentioned, then [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/horizon)

Comment: Using queue events am I able to also log the piece of code that dispatched the job as well?

Comment: Laravel Horizon will do it for you.